# create and move a point on canvas at once

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I got a Problem with creating and moving a point (an ellipse) in WPF MVVM.

Right now i have a RelayCommand which calls my create point handler in my vm which creates a command and executes it:

```
private void CreatePointHandler(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        AddConnectionPointCommand addConnectionPointCommand = new AddConnectionPointCommand(this, e);
        PetriNetViewModel.ExecuteCommand(addConnectionPointCommand);            
    }
```

Furthermore for an already existing point, I got a Move handler aswell (in another vm tho):

```
public void MovePointHandler(ConnectionPoint pointMoved, Point oldLocation, Point newLocation)
    {
        Vector move = new Vector(newLocation.X - oldLocation.X, newLocation.Y - oldLocation.Y);
        PetriNetViewModel.ExecuteCommand(new MoveDragCanvasElementsCommand(new ConnectionPoint[] { pointMoved }, move));
    }
```

Adding and moving a point afterwards is just working as expected.

Now i want to give the user the possibility to add and move a point in one step. In my `CreatePointHandler` i can figure out if the left mouse buttin it still pressed like this:

```
if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) {             
}
```

but how would I move the point now? The `MovePointHandler` is called by an event in the codebehind (I know this shouldnt be done in mvvm, but my collegues and I think it's ok if you don't have too much code in it), which is also passing an `ElementsMovedEventArgs` which I dont have here.

thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you ask me. MVVM is not about having no codebehind but to seperate concerns. View things belong in the view. Business things in the ViewModel. The ViewModel is not supposed to know how a View works. It just exposes certain data and command to any possible view.

Comment: What's the point in adding and moving? Surely, that just the same as adding a `Point` somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your codebehind that calls these handlers.

I would have thought you should have a concept of a **SelectedPoint**, at which you can always check if there is an intended drag happening when the mouse is moved.

i.e.

```
private ConnectionPoint SelectedPoint { get; set; }

private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        // dragging something.. check if there is a point selected
        if (SelectedPoint != null)
        {
             _viewModel.MovePointHandler(SelectedPoint, _oldLocation, _newLocation);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, as part of your **CreatePointHandler**, you immediately set the newly created instance to the **SelectedPoint**, until a **MouseUp** is detected.

```
private void ExecuteAddConnectionPointCommand()
{
    // standard logic...
    ConnectionPoint addedPoint = ...

    SelectedPoint = addedPoint;
}
```

The specifics of the implementation will likely change depending on your architecture, but hopefully you get the point.